# Is there a way to intercept the result of a WMI query?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wmi, wmi-query

I have this code that make a call to WMI using a query to fecth the display information:

```
var success = true;

List<Display> displays = new List<Display>();

// Query WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams to retrieve display parameters
using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"Root\WMI", "SELECT * FROM 
WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams"))

using (var results = searcher.Get())
```

Withouth changing the original code, is there a way to externally intercept the result of this WMI query, change it, and then return it to the code?

Comment: What would be the purpose?

Comment: Please define "externally" - do you have access (locally, or through specific remoting protocols?) to the box running the process hosting the application?

Comment: Not without changing this code. You could e.g., add it an event allowing a subscriber to filter the result.

Comment: The purpose is that i'm trying to run this app in a virtual machine, but this app fail to fetch my display information and the crash, so the only thing i've thought is to intercept the result of the query containg the exception of being unable to read the display info and then modify it. When i said externally i mean something like creating a script to would run, catch that query when sendend, and send it back modified